# invalid literal w/ python range extraction

Tags: python, integer, range, literals

Can someone explain to me what makes the below return an invalid literal?

```
def solution(args):
    new_args = []
    for i in args:
        if i > (i - 1) and i > (i - 2):
            new_args.append("{}-{}".format((i - 2), i))
    return list(map(float, new_args))
```

Exact error was: `ValueError: invalid literal for float()`

Example input:

```
-6,-3,-2,-1,0,1,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,14,15,17,18,19,20
```

Example output:

```
-6,-3-1,3-5,7-11,14,15,17-20
```

which you'll notice is a consolidated list, converted to a string, where any three original inputs that are consecutive would now be represented in a range within the list.

Comment: Look at the contents of `new_args`. They are strings. Are they strings you can pass to `float`?

Comment: It looks like you wanted `float` to calculate a subtraction expression, but float doesn't do that. It will attempt to convert a string representation of a float to a float, but it knows nothing of math.

Comment: `float` does not evaluate a numeric expression such as `'1-2'` for you, it just takes a string `__repr__` of a float and constructs the corresponding `float` object.

Comment: This is just a hunch, but do you expect `i - 1` to be the value that comes before `i` in `args`?  Because `i > i - 1` is always going to be true, so I don't see why you're checking it.

Comment: Give us an example of `args` and the output expected

Comment: test input is `-6,-3,-2,-1,0,1,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,14,15,17,18,19,20` and corresponding test output would be `'-6,-3-1,3-5,7-11,14,15,17-20'` which you'll notice is a consolidated list, converted to a string, where any three original inputs that are consecutive would now be represented in a range within the list.

Comment: @Mr.Jibz My answer is ready to be accepted - and YOU, are you ready to accept it?

Comment: What do you hope for the `float` to accomplish? In other words, why are you not simply returning `new_args`, or perhaps the string `','.join(new_args)`?

Answer (score 0):

The could be much speculation about what is here going on and why is that this way, BUT ... let's leave the path of trying out what is possible and what not. The code below is a patch to the problem without changing the logic behind `solution()`, so I consider it an acceptable answer to the question:

```
def solution(args):
    new_args = []
    for i in args:
        if i > (i - 1) and i > (i - 2):
            new_args.append("{}-{}".format((i - 2), i))
    return list(map(float, map(eval, new_args)))
```

I haven't checked this out in detail in the documentation, but it comes to my mind that the int()/float() functions aren't designed to take any strings which are not representations of an integer/float number. It sounds quite reasonable that they shouldn't evaluate the expression before interpreting the content, right? Putting eval() in front of the conversion does the right job and fixes the problem.

For these ones who are still curious what actually causes the error:

```
print(float('-1-1'))
   ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-1-1'
print(int('-1-1'))
   ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-1-1'
```

In this context I have to admit that **I was surprised to see it happen** ... because my *intuition* whispered that the interpreter will guess what to do and just do the one more operation on the string ... but it doesn't.

> **In case of ambiguity resist the temptation to guess!**

is one of the known to me leading ideas behind Python.

So int('-1-1') is ambiguous in context of int() and float(). Is the problem the missing space between two numbers? Is it a special notation? Is it addition/subtraction? Why bother? Just raise an error and reject it.

Comment: from `int` to `str`, and back to `int`. Doesn't seem like the most effective approach. Certainly not the most readable approach.

Comment: `eval` is always pesky.  If you know you want to limit the scope to numbers, why don't you convert them both to floats, then subtract them?

Comment: @tripleee Fully agree with you, but ...NOTICE that the code in the question doesn't make any sense in each possible aspect - maybe it's just only trolling? Anyway the question was why does it happen and the code and the comments provided by me answer sufficiently the question without criticizing the question as such, ok?